# I am trying to optimize my ruby else if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find out if there is a more elegant way to write this piece of code:

```
result.each_with_index do |rowset,index|

    if rowset["Answer"].to_i == 0   
        puts "1"    
    end

    if rowset["Answer"].to_i == 1   
        puts "2"
    end

    if rowset["Answer"].to_i == 2   
        puts "3"        
    end

    if rowset["Answer"].to_i == 3   
        puts "4"
    end
```

Comment: You may want to read about the [case expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
result = [{"Answer"=>"1"}, {"Answer"=>"3"}]
puts result.map(&-> v { v["Answer"].next })
```

Outputs:

```
2
4
=> nil
```

Comment: we are not sure, if OP has only one key.. Be safe :-)

Comment: I could have mapped to answer but I hate writing the block. In my apps, I usually have `method_missing` on `Hash` to do the lookup: in my case, `map(&:Answer)` works beautifully :-)

Comment: And hey... like the `Enumerator::Lazy` usage here?

Comment: +1.. .. `.map(&-> v { v["Answer"].next })` is nice usage of `lambda`.

Answer (score 6):

I would do then using [`String#next`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-next) :

```
 # no need to do `String#to_i` method call.
 result.each { |rowset| puts rowset['Answer'].next }
```

Comment: Great use of String#next ! :-) +1

Comment: @Abdo Thanks.. I have been attacked :-)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
result.each do |rowset|
  puts rowset["Answer"].to_i + 1
end
```

Comment: You can remove `index`

Comment: OP is checking only `0..4`... Why you didn't check that ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Or he just posted first 4 lines and he is in fact checking 0..300 :)

Comment: @Damien: why `each_with_index` and not use the index?